# BufferedImage won't show

Tags: user-interface, graphics, paint, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

I've been trying to create a JPanel with a BufferedImage in it, the paintComponent method runs and compiles along with the constructor code that initialises the BufferedImage. Still, nothing's showing in the JFrame when I run the GUI. Any ideas? Feel free to point out any errors in my code!

Note: you may notice all of my JButtons do System.exit, I am aware of that and it is so merely for testing purposes.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class IntroductionComponent extends JPanel {

    /**
    * Generated SVUID
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1355536543860254435L;
private BufferedImage img;
private Audio audio;

public IntroductionComponent() {
    try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/KChel-2/Downloads/HauntedHouse.jpg"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

JButton start = new JButton("Start");
start.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

JButton opt = new JButton("Options");
opt.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

JButton cred = new JButton("Credits");
cred.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
exit.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
buttons.add(start);
buttons.add(opt);
buttons.add(cred);
buttons.add(exit);
add(buttons);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);           
       }

//Audio.sound1.loop();
}



import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class IntroductionGUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    IntroductionComponent comp = new IntroductionComponent();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Story");
    frame.setSize(1600, 850);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(comp);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    IntroductionComponent comp = new IntroductionComponent();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Story");
    frame.setSize(1600, 850);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(comp);

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    start.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

    JButton opt = new JButton("Options");
    opt.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

    JButton cred = new JButton("Credits");
    cred.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));

    buttons.add(start);
    buttons.add(opt);
    buttons.add(cred);
    buttons.add(exit);
    frame.add(buttons);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

or you can create a buttons panel class.